# How to display Validation messages on New Form in pop up alerts?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, validation

I want to display Validation messages in my New Form as pop up alerts.I am using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the SharePoint `PreSaveAction`

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=presaveaction